# TreeView Select parent checkbox based on children - WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox, treeview

I am new to WPF. I found a few examples and put together a tree-view example in C# WPF Mvvm. I got the children's checkboxes checked or unchecked based on parent selection. I am not sure how to access the parent binding or property to check or uncheck it based on children. If all children are selected, I expect parents to be checked, and if even one child is unchecked, I want parents to be unchecked. How do I achieve this using the MVVM viewmodel? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Xaml View

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel></local:MainViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CheckableItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding 
        Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, 
                                                Path=DataContext.CheckBoxCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Miscellaneous Imports" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MiscellaneousImports, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="10" Height="450"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand CheckBoxCommand { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        LoadCheckableItems();
        CheckBoxCommand = new DelegateCommand<CheckableItem>(OnCheckBoxChecked);
    }

    private void OnCheckBoxChecked(CheckableItem item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> miscellaneousImports;
    public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> MiscellaneousImports
    {
        
        get { return miscellaneousImports; }
        set
        {
            miscellaneousImports = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MiscellaneousImports");
        }
    }
    private void LoadCheckableItems()
    {
        List<CheckableItem> lstItems = new List<CheckableItem>();

        CheckableItem item = new CheckableItem
        { Name = "Coffee", Children = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>() { new CheckableItem { Name="Medium" }, new CheckableItem {Name="Dark" } } };
        lstItems.Add(item);

        MiscellaneousImports = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> ( lstItems );
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Checkbox collection class

```
public class CheckableItem:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> Children { get; set; }
        private bool _isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                if (Children != null)
                {
                    foreach (CheckableItem child in Children)
                    {
                        child.IsChecked = IsChecked;
                    }
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Children));
                }
            }
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked to implement the behavior in the view model. But you should consider implementing the behavior inside the item model itself. The item model already implements selection behavior as it delegates the selection state to all its children.
Either implement the behavior inside the item model or inside the view model that owns the items. Don't mix both. Be consistent.

However, you have to modify the item model and add a `SelectionChanged` event to enable the parent to observe its children. If you require to traverse the tree towards the root, then your model needs a `Parent` property. In this case you can completely remove the `SelectionChanged` event as you have direct access to the parent.
I decided to introduce the event because your item model doesn't have such parent property, which made me assume that you are not interested in traversing towards the root. A parent property would make initialization of an item more complex (as the correct parent reference has to be set).

Additionally, if the selection state is only for the visual presentation (and is irrelevant at data level) you can improve performance by not modifying the complete subtree as soon as the parent has changed. Instead wait until the children have become visible (expanded). For this purpose, the item models must also define an `IsExpanded` property that you can bind to the `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` property.
Note, if the selection state is exclusively for the visual presentation, then the complete logic of the below example has to be moved to the `TreeViewItem` (either by extending it or by implementing an attached behavior) because the `TreeViewItem` already comes with similar features. For example, it already has `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` properties and exposes API to expand subtrees. Therefore the custom or extended logic will fit perfectly to the `TreeViewItem`.
But if the selection state is relevant at data level, then simply follow the example below.

Normally the data models are more abstract and not a representation of UI controls. As such these types and their members would not be named e.g. `CheckBoxModel` class and `IsChecked` property.

**CheckableItem.cs**

```cs
class CheckableItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public CheckableItem()
  {
    this.Children = new ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>();
  }

    // Internal IsSelected property setter to enable control of value propagation along the tree.
  private void SetIsSelectedInternal(bool isSelected, bool isPropagateToAncestorsEnabled, bool isPropagateToDescendantsEnabled)
  {
    if (this.isSelected == isSelected)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.isSelected = isSelected;

    if (isPropagateToDescendantsEnabled)
    {
      HandleChildSelection();
    }

    if (isPropagateToAncestorsEnabled)
    {
      OnSelectionChanged(this.IsSelected);
    }

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.IsSelected));
  }

  private void HandleChildSelection()
  {
    if (this.IsSelected)
    {
      SelectAllChildren();
    }
    else
    {
      UnselectAllChildren();
    }
  }

  private void SelectAllChildren()
  {
    foreach (CheckableItem child in this.Children)
    {
      child.SetIsSelectedInternal(isSelected: true, isPropagateToAncestorsEnabled: false, isPropagateToDescendantsEnabled: true);
    }

    this.SelectedChildrenCount = this.Children.Count;
  }

  private void UnselectAllChildren()
  {
    foreach (CheckableItem child in this.Children)
    {
      child.SetIsSelectedInternal(isSelected: false, isPropagateToAncestorsEnabled: false, isPropagateToDescendantsEnabled: true);
    }

    this.SelectedChildrenCount = 0;
  }

  private void RegisterChildren()
    => OnChildCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, this.Children));

  private void UnregisterChildren()
    => OnChildCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, this.Children));

  private void OnChildCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    switch (e.Action)
    {
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        foreach (CheckableItem newItem in e.NewItems.Cast<CheckableItem>())
        {
          newItem.SelectionChanged += OnChildSelectionChanged;
        }
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
        foreach (CheckableItem oldItem in e.OldItems.Cast<CheckableItem>())
        {
          oldItem.SelectionChanged -= OnChildSelectionChanged;
        }
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
        foreach (CheckableItem oldItem in this.Children)
        {
          oldItem.SelectionChanged -= OnChildSelectionChanged;
        }
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
        break;
    }
  }

  private void OnChildSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.IsSelected)
    {
      this.SelectedChildrenCount++;
    }
    else
    {
      this.SelectedChildrenCount--;
    }

    // Select parent (this) if all children are selected
    // or unselect if any child is unselected.
    // Use a counter to avoid iteration of children to improve performance. 
    // (worst case: each ancestor has to iterate over all children to check if they are all selected 
    // ==> a counter turns the iteration into a single comparison.   
    bool newIsSelected = this.SelectedChildrenCount == this.Children.Count;
    if (newIsSelected != this.IsSelected)
    {
      SetIsSelectedInternal(isSelected: newIsSelected, isPropagateToAncestorsEnabled: true, isPropagateToDescendantsEnabled: false);
    }
  }

  protected virtual void OnSelectionChanged(bool isSelected)
    => this.SelectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new SelectionChangedEventArgs(isSelected);

  protected virtual OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectionChanged;
  
  private ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> children;   
  public ObservableCollection<CheckableItem> Children
  {
    get => this.children;
    set
    {
      if (this.Children is INotifyCollectionChanged oldCollection) 
      {
        oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= OnChildCollectionChanged;
        UnregisterChildren();
      }

      this.children = value;
     
      if (value is INotifyCollectionChanged newCollection)
      {
        newCollection.CollectionChanged += OnChildCollectionChanged;
        RegisterChildren();
      }
    }
  }

  private bool isSelected;
  public bool IsSelected // Bind to CheckBox.IsSelected (TwoWay)
  {
    get => this.isSelected; 
    set => SetIsSelectedInternal(isSelected: value, isPropagateToAncestorsEnabled: true, isPropagateToDescendantsEnabled: true);
  }

  private string title;   
  public string Title
  {
    get => this.title;
    set
    { 
      this.title = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this. Title));
  }

  private int SelectedChildrenCount { get; set; }
}
```

**SelectionChangedEventArgs.cs**

```cs
public class SelectionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public SelectionChangedEventArgs(bool isSelected) 
    => this.IsSelected = isSelected;

  public bool IsSelected { get; }
}
```

```xml
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="local:CheckableItem"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                Content="{Binding Title}" />
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just trying to figure out whats the purpose of    protected virtual void OnSelectionChanged(bool isSelected)

Comment: Also the event SelectionChanged  is not called

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.  I previously had an example with a parent and decided to discard it because you were not interested in parent relations in the first place (no need to traverse the tree towards the root).

Comment: I have updated the example and also improved the implementation to improve performance and also to fix potential bugs.  So, you should review the complete example again. The example should now compile and execute.